# open new ViewController automatiocally after a certain time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to create a new App. How can I open a new ViewController automatically after a certain time i-e 5 seconds.
Please explain answer because I'm new on XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class `NSTimer` for this.
The following line of code schedules a certain method to be called after a certain time (3 seconds):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

In the method myMethod, you can simply push a new view controller:

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

Edit: Here's how you can do it with Swift:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.myMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func myMethod() 
{
    let vc = UIViewController.init()
    self.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: OP is looking for a swift syntax I believe by the tag he used.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added the Swift syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use present view controller after time. Please refer to [this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift) for details.

BR